# Chrome extension POST Request throttled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a Chrome extension that sends a post request to the server every 3 sec. After 2 successful requests, the extension throws an error " Request throttled. Visit http://dev.chromium.org/throttling for more information.".

How do I prevent or avoid this from happening from the extension ? This error kills the Chrome extension.

Comment: The linked document in the error message is pretty much self-explanatory. You need to check the server status code and if it's 500 or greater you need to delay the next request yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I tried delaying before up to 30sec and it didn't work. But now I tried delaying up to 1min and it seems to work fine.